# PSPDFKIt Created PDF not opening in ios safari browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf-viewer, pspdfkit

Using PSPDFkit 7.0 version and I created PDF file.

This files are working perfectly in all browsers and PDF viewer applications. But one problem is **IOS Device browsers safari,Chrome and Firefox is not showing this documents.** Its showing empty document.

But when i open this pdf in iBook,File browsers and other PDF viewer applications its working perfectly.

My code as follows:

```
- (void)pdfDocumentDidSave:(PSPDFDocument *)document {
    NSLog(@"Successfully saved document.");

            //Get path directory
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            //Create PDF_Documents directory
            documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF_Documents"];
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

            NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"hello123.pdf"];


    // Create default configuration
    PSPDFProcessorConfiguration *configuration = [[PSPDFProcessorConfiguration alloc] initWithDocument:document];

[configuration modifyAnnotationsOfTypes:PSPDFAnnotationTypeAll change:PSPDFAnnotationChangeEmbed];


    // Start the conversion from `document` to `scaledDocumentURL`
    [PSPDFProcessor generatePDFFromConfiguration:configuration securityOptions:nil outputFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] progressBlock:nil error:NULL];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not use the [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) PDF SDK. 
You load a file into memory, build another file path and store the loaded file into that path.

I'm happy to take a closer look and help you debug this issue if you share the PSPDFKit API code you use to create the file.

As additional data point, you can also compare loading a PDF via iOS Safari, which uses the Apple internal renderer, and then compare it with [PDF Viewer by PSPDFKit](https://pdfviewer.io/), our free app available for iOS and Android which includes our own proprietary render engine.

PSPDFKit is a commercial SDK for annotating documents, filling out forms and also for creating PDF documents. We offer commercial support for customer both evaluating a license and for license owners. Please report your ticket to our [support page](https://pspdfkit.com/support/request/) - Thanks!

Note: As we are available on iOS, Android, Web, Web Standalone, macOS and Windows, please also detail on which platform and via what version you created the document - lots of combinations and we want to help you effectively.

Edit: Thanks for adding the code and for submitting the same to our support. This is an issue related to [Third-Party Compatibility](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/miscellaneous/3rd-party-compatibility/), it will work using compliant PDF renderers such as Adobe Acrobat.